# How can AMCharts 4 be scrolled horizontally from javascript code?

Tags: amcharts

I am trying to get the chart scrolled horizontally from externally triggered event calls like when a button is clicked elsewhere on the page. I am equally able to get the start and indexes of where i want the chart horizontally scrolled to. The chart's DateAxis is defined as below:

```
this.categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
this.categoryAxis.dataFields.date = "value_date";
this.categoryAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;
this.categoryAxis.start = 0.7;
this.categoryAxis.keepSelection = true;
```

And the function that is called by an external event is defined as below:

```
      function(res){
       let cpre = res.tree.split(',');
       cpre.forEach((el, i) => {
         cpre[i] = Number(el);
       });
       let visibleEl = this.data.findIndex((el, i) => {
         return isEqual(cpre, el.graphIndex);
       });
       console.log(visibleEl);
       //Trying to display 6 date points at any given time, not working.
       let startIndex = visibleEl - 6 < 0 ? 0 : visibleEl - 6;
       this.categoryAxis.zoomToIndexes(visibleEl, startIndex);
      }
```

This line `this.categoryAxis.zoomToIndexes(visibleEl, startIndex);` currently zooms to the target indexes, but also zooms in the map which is not the desired effect. I only want to have it scroll to the desired position without zooming, thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your complete config vor create a code pen?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `valueAxis.strictMinMax` ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#strictMinMax_property)).

```
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
```

If that doesn't work try to use `dateAxis.zoomToDates()` instead of `zoomToIndexes` ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#zoomToDates_method)).